# S. pyogenes' skin infection diagnostics

Tags: microbiology, skin

*S. pyogenes* is "flesh-eating" bacteria.
It results from life-theatening **myonecrosis** caused by this organism.
*S. pyogenes* avoids phagocytosis (mediated primarily by capsule, M and M-like proteins, C5a peptidase), adhere to and invade host cells (M protein, lipoteichoic, F protein), and produce toxins (streptococcal pyrogenic exotoxins, steptolysin S, streptolsin O, streptokinase, DNases).

Suppurative diseases: pharyngitis, soft-tissue infections.

**Erysipelas**: localised skin infection with pain, inflammation, lymph node enlargement and systemic symptoms.

**Cellulitis**: infection of the skin that involves the subcutaneous tissues.

**Necrotising fasciitis**: deep infection of skin that involves destruction of muscle and fat layers.

I think these are most its skin infections. But what about its diagnostics?

I think take biopsy from living tissue, not from necrotic.
If pus, then probably from it.
I think we can do Gram staining, recognise gram-positive cocci like in a string
Then, we can do hydrogen peroxide test - if no bubbles, then suspicion to *S. pyogenes*, since catalase negative.
The do optochin test which is positive for *S. pyogenes*.

**What is the correct procedure for doing skin infection diagnostics for group A streptococci?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*S. pyogenes* cultured on Blood Agar should show beta-hemolysis. B-hemolytic colonies can be further identified as *S. pyogenes* by the results of negative catalase (hydrogen peroxide) test, positive L-pyrrolidonyl arylamidase (PYR) reaction ([1](http://www.cdc.gov/ncidod/biotech/strep/strep-doc/section1.htm#25)) and sensitivity to Bacitracin ([2](http://www.cdc.gov/ncidod/biotech/strep/strep-doc/section1.htm#5)). See https://www.inkling.com/read/medical-microbiology-murray-rosenthal-pfaller-7th/chapter-19/streptococcus-pyogenes

PCR may also be used: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0923250805000215